# running ESP command using ssh

Tags: bash, shell, mainframe

i am new to unix and ESP.
I am trying to run an ESP command using ssh :

`ssh neodusr@inda01hdie01d.neo.com /usr/local/ESPSystemAgent_R22L5/ESPlmi -sdevl.neo.com:9500 -uPK001 -ppk1234# "-cTRIGGER devlNEO.NEOFD110_EXTRACT"`

this is not working as expected and is giving me the below error :

```
Syntax: ESPlmi -shost:port -uuserid -ppassword -ccmd -h

When specifying an option that takes an argument, do not enter a
space between the option and the argument.  For example:
        ESPlmi -slpara:1234
```

although there is no space between the option and the arguments.
what am i doing wrong? any help is highly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: I think that information is part of the `-h` (help) output, not an error. Try running commands as per whatever the documentation says. (I've not used ESP, that was a quick check at their website)

Comment: I do not see how this is a mainframe question. However, I would suggest that the -c should be before the quotes.